# How to add CheckBox to any ListView item in android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm writing an app with ListView layout and i want to add to any line
in this ListView CheckBox.
How can i do this?

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ListView
               android:id="@+id/listView"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1">
       </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks
Moshik.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a BaseAdapter. You can see an example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html). You can pretty much add anything in a list item. You do that by overriding the getView method of the BaseAdapter. You could either create the View and add the CheckBox programmatically or you could use an xml resource file and LayoutInflater. The latter technique is used in the linked example.